# I got error message "TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating '_reactNative.NativeModules.PlaidAndroid.startLinkActivityForResult')"

Tags: react-native, expo

I installed react-native-plaid-link-sdk and did all the documantation steps, and when I trey to run the app on android emulatore I get error message "TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating '_reactNative.NativeModules.PlaidAndroid.startLinkActivityForResult')
"

I am using Expo Bare workflow.

Here is my code:

```
import {LinkExit, LinkSuccess, PlaidLink} from "react-native-plaid-link-sdk";

const IdVerificationPage = () => {
    const [token, setToken] = useState('')
    useEffect(()=> {
        (async () => {
            const response = await LoginApis.createLinkToken()
            console.log(response, '===========')
            setToken(response)
        })()
    }, [])

    return (
        <View style={{flex: 1, display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
            <PlaidLink
                tokenConfig={{
                    token: token,
                    noLoadingState: false
                }}
                onSuccess={(success: LinkSuccess) => {
                    console.log(success);
                }}
                onExit={(exit: LinkExit) => {
                    console.log(exit);
                }}
            >

                    <Text>Add Account</Text>
            </PlaidLink>
        </View>
    )
}

export default IdVerificationPage
```